# Converting Image-Based ECG to numerical form

Tags: python, image, image-processing, conv-neural-network, medical

I'm having an issue in transforming the image of a plot or an ECG to be specific to the numerical format, the link shows how my image is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qR7p.jpg). Is there a way in python to convert an image to it's original format?

I've tried pixel conversion but it doesn't seem to give any valuable information.

Comment: Is the section marked aVF a continuation of the section marked III, or is it a completely different section that happens to be next to it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This library might work: https://pypi.org/project/plotdigitizer/

Comment: @NickODell Yes, it's a continuation.

Comment: @NickODell Nick, you are a god man, it worked perfectly, thanks for helping me out, appreciate it buddy! much love.

Comment: i was going to suggest `cv2`, but i see you have a more suitable suggestion from @NickODell.  i have upvoted this question...

Comment: @D.L Kindly inform me about the cv2 method.

Comment: @DustinZiuter,  the open-cv library here: https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python. Also, the middle chapters of this book are helpful for image processing: https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0BHL2XKCR .